# Independent network module - regardless of library used

Tags: android, networking, module, retrofit2, android-library

Problem : 
We have a large android application, whose development started 3 years ago. At that time, devs used Volley for networking. Now we want to replace it with Retrofit. As the app is huge, it will take time and effort to do that. 
Solution:
I want to develop a separate network module, which can be used with any project along with default `app` module. In future, if we get better networking libraries then we should not have to change app module. Problem in developing this approach is Retrofit instance is tightly coupled with interface having all apis information. 
Perfect solution we want: 
from `app` module, send base_url, endpoint, headers, body, Request bean, Response bean type to `network` module. Network module will call the api and provide callback. Replacing retrofit with any xyz library in future should not affect in `app` module.

Comment: OK, then do that, but you have not actually asked any question. In fact, what your post contains is really too broad.

Comment: Any critics on my answer @Harish Gyanani?

Answer (score 2):

You're asking a very generic question. There isn't one way to achieve this, and there are certainly better and worse approaches, all valid depending on a lot of factors. Therefore nobody can give you proper advice without more context.

I would argue that if you're trying to "build an independent network module" just because you don't want to remove retrofit in three years (like you're doing now with Volley), then I'd say you're putting the cart ahead of the horse. Retrofit, for all intents and purposes, is almost a sub-default behind using plain OkHttp. It's a nice to have tool to simplify the abstraction of performing common HTTP/REST operations and the involved serialization deserialization.

That being said, Retrofit seems to be here to stay, at least until Square gets bored or Gooogle "Acquires it"; or until a newer better appears. (I'd expect to see a Retorfit-kt at some point, but not sure what the true benefits will be, perhaps from some KT magic).

In any case, all you need to do is, create a Gradle Module/Android LIbrary, expose some interfaces with what you just described, and have your app refer to these interfaces instead of the pure retrofit stuff.

Inside said module, you will obviously depend on retrofit, and this will be the sole retrofit point of contact. Every time your app needs to do something that is retrofit related, you should provide your own classes and interfaces to *proxy* Retrofit.

If in the future a new library shows up, your interfaces and classes that are proxying retorfit, will continue to proxy the `NewNotRetrofit` library you are going to be hypothetically using in said distant future.

If you think about this from a little bit higher, this is what Retrofit is doing for you when it comes to OkHttp, HTTP/2 and the REST terminology. If, say, HTTP/3 became a thing tomorrow (it's already happening), there would be a Retrofit3 that would support it, but *you* from your "repository/viewmodel/whatever" wouldn't have to worry too much about it, sans perhaps providing an few extra parameters or whatever HTTP/3 needs that HTTP/2 doesn't.

Ultimately, retrofit is shielding you from all this, abstracting the complexity away. You're trying to do the same with your app, abstract this "network" complexity away.

And this is how you'd do it.

#### Is this worth doing with Retrofit vs. Volley?

No.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you are basically looking for:

```
class Network(
    var context: Context,
    var webResponse: WebResponse?,
    var hashMap: HashMap<String, Any>,
    var url: String = "https://yourbaseurl",
    var endpoint: Endpoints,
    var isGetRequest: Boolean = false,
    var headers: HashMap<String, Any>? = null,
    private var TAG: String = "Network"
){

    enum class Endpoints(val rawValue: String) {
        LOGIN("login"),
        REGISTER("register")
    }

    interface WebResponse {
        fun onWebResponse(endpoint: Endpoints, response: String)
    }

    fun execute(){

    }
}
```

How to use it:
And here is how to use it:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), Network.WebResponse {

    fun executeQuery(endpoint: Network.Endpoints) {
        val map = hashMapOf<String, Any>()
        when (endpoint) {
            Network.Endpoints.LOGIN -> {
                map["email"] = "email"
                map["password"] = "password"
            }
            Network.Endpoints.REGISTER -> {
                map["email"] = "email"
                map["password"] = "password"
            }
        }
        Network(this, this, map, endpoint = endpoint).execute()

    }

    override fun onWebResponse(endpoint: Network.Endpoints, response: String) {
        when(endpoint){
            Network.Endpoints.LOGIN->{
//                You can do the parsing here or use GSON
            }
            Network.Endpoints.REGISTER->{

            }
        }
    }
}
```

To make it compatible with [OKHTTP](https://square.github.io/okhttp/):

```
class Network(
    var context: Context,
    var webResponse: WebResponse?,
    var hashMap: HashMap<String, Any>,
    var url: String = "https://example.com",
    var endpoint: Endpoints,
    var isGetRequest: Boolean = false,
    var headers: HashMap<String, Any>? = null,
    private var TAG: String = "Network"
) : AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {

    enum class Endpoints(val rawValue: String) {
        LOGIN("login"),
        REGISTER("register")
    }

    interface WebResponse {
        fun onWebResponse(endpoint: Endpoints, response: String)
    }

    private fun logRequest() {
        val builder = StringBuilder()
        hashMap.forEach {
            builder.append("\n")
                .append(it.key)
                .append(":")
                .append(it.value.toString())
        }
        Log.e(TAG, url)
        Log.e(TAG, builder.toString())
    }

    private fun commonParameters(context: Context): HashMap<String, Any> {
        val hasmap: HashMap<String, Any> = hashMapOf()
        hasmap["device"] = "Android"
        hasmap["device_version"] = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
        hasmap["device_name"] = Build.MANUFACTURER + " , " + Build.MODEL
        return hasmap
    }

    override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: String?): String {
        try {
            hashMap.putAll(commonParameters(context))
            val headersBuilder = Headers.Builder()
            headers?.forEach { headersBuilder.add(it.key, it.value.toString()) }
            url += endpoint.rawValue
            var builder = Request.Builder().url(url).headers(headersBuilder.build())
            if (isGetRequest) {
                val urlBuilder = Uri.parse(this.url).buildUpon()
                for (entry in hashMap.entries) {
                    hashMap.forEach { urlBuilder.appendQueryParameter(it.key, it.value.toString()) }
                }
                url = builder.build().toString()
            } else {
                val body: FormBody.Builder = FormBody.Builder()
                hashMap.forEach { body.add(it.key, it.value.toString()) }
                builder = builder.post(body.build())
            }
            logRequest()
            val request = builder.build()
            val response = OkHttpClient.Builder().build().newCall(request).execute()
            return if (response.isSuccessful) response.body()?.string() ?: "" else ""
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e))
        }
        return ""
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        Log.e(TAG, endpoint.rawValue + ": " + result)
        webResponse?.onWebResponse(endpoint, result ?: "")
    }
}
```

To make it compatible with [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/):

```
class Network(
    var context: Context,
    var webResponse: WebResponse?,
    var hashMap: HashMap<String, Any>,
    var url: String = "https://example.com",
    var endpoint: Endpoints,
    var isGetRequest: Boolean = false,
    var headers: HashMap<String, Any>? = null,
    private var TAG: String = "Network"
) {

    enum class Endpoints(val rawValue: String) {
        LOGIN("login"),
        REGISTER("register")
    }

    interface WebResponse {
        fun onWebResponse(endpoint: Endpoints, response: String)
    }

    private fun logRequest() {
        val builder = StringBuilder()
        hashMap.forEach {
            builder.append("\n")
                .append(it.key)
                .append(":")
                .append(it.value.toString())
        }
        Log.e(TAG, url)
        Log.e(TAG, builder.toString())
    }

    private fun commonParameters(context: Context): HashMap<String, Any> {
        val hasmap: HashMap<String, Any> = hashMapOf()
        hasmap["device"] = "Android"
        hasmap["device_version"] = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
        hasmap["device_name"] = Build.MANUFACTURER + " , " + Build.MODEL
        return hasmap
    }


    fun execute() {
        url += endpoint.rawValue
        var method = if (isGetRequest) Request.Method.GET else Request.Method.POST

        val request = object : StringRequest(method, url, Response.Listener {
            webResponse?.onWebResponse(endpoint, it)
        }, Response.ErrorListener //Create an error listener to handle errors appropriately.
        {
            Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(it.fillInStackTrace()))
            webResponse?.onWebResponse(endpoint, "");
        }) {
            override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
                val body = HashMap<String, String>()
                hashMap.forEach { body[it.key] = it.value.toString() }
                commonParameters(context).forEach { body[it.key] = it.value.toString() }
                return body
            }

            override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                var requestHeaders  = super.getHeaders()
                this@Network.headers?.forEach { requestHeaders[it.key] = it.value.toString()  }
                logRequest()
                return requestHeaders
            }
        }
        MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(request)
    }
}

class MySingleton constructor(context: Context) {
    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: MySingleton? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context) =
            INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                INSTANCE ?: MySingleton(context).also {
                    INSTANCE = it
                }
            }
    }

    val requestQueue: RequestQueue by lazy {
        // applicationContext is key, it keeps you from leaking the
        // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
        Volley.newRequestQueue(context.applicationContext)
    }

    fun <T> addToRequestQueue(req: Request<T>) {
        requestQueue.add(req)
    }
}
```

KeyPoints

1. Endpoints are defined as enum with String value. This end point is appended to url in execution method e.g. look at doInBackground(OKhttp) & in execute method(Volley)
2. It uses [interface](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html) as a callback i.e. WebResponse
3. `logRequest()` is basically used for debugging purpose. it will log all the parameters which are being sent in the request
4. Network class currently supports HTTP GET & POST. You can add support to other  HTTP methods.
5. With the Network class, your logic in other classes will remain the same and gives you the flexibility to change the network library.
6. Volley Example has another class `MySingleton` as mentioned by Google in their [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue#singleton)